# Extend an Angular service with Events

Tags: angularjs, events, mediator

Is there a way to extend an object returned by an Angular Service, Factory, or Provider with event pub/sub?

I'd like to do something like:

```
angular.module('app').factory('user', function(Event){
  var user = {
    // User methods...
  };
  return angular.extend(user, Event);
})

// In a distant time and place...
angular.module('app').directive('nav', function(user){
  scope: true,
  templateUrl: 'something',
  link: function(scope){
    user.on('logIn', function(user){
      scope.user = user
    })
  }
})
```

I accomplished something similar with promises. That is usually a good way to communicate asynchronously out of a service, but a user can log out and in, and promises only resolve once. Events are a better fit here.

I also understand I could solve this by broadcasting/emiting on `$rootScope` and listening on `scope`, but I think that is smelly. :)

What kinds of things patterns have you guys come up with to mediate between services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm use (a modified version of) a pubsub service that you can check out [here](https://github.com/phiggins42/bloody-jquery-plugins/blob/master/pubsub.js).

You can read about the trade offs for $rootScope events and pubsub with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21638563/2728255)

Hope this helped

Comment: That plugin is nice and tiny, I like it. Sounds like the answer is plugging in something outside of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this same problem.  Particularly how to allow services to broadcast and subscribe to events without accessing $rootScope (bad for a few reasons).
I utilized the very excellent js-signals implementation from here :
http://millermedeiros.github.io/js-signals/
and wrapped it into an angular service.

github gist here : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b552c7fafa77427e6d06