# Communication between controllers in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I'm familiar with the following methods to implement communication between controllers.

Are there others? Are there better approaches / best practices?

## `$broadcast`/`$emit`

```
.controller("Parent", function($scope){
  $scope.$broadcast("SomethingHappened", {..});
  $scope.$on("SomethingElseHappened", function(e, d){..});
})
.controller("Child", functions($scope){
  $scope.$broadcast("SomethingElseHappened", {..});
  $scope.$on("SomethingHappened", function(e, d){..});
})
.controller("AnotherChild", functions($scope){
  $scope.$on("SomethingHappened", function(e, d){..});
});
```

or, from the View:

```
<button ng-click="$broadcast('SomethingHappened', data)">Do Something</button>
```

**Advantages:**

- Good for one-time events

**Disadvantages:**

- Does not work between siblings, unless a common ancestor, like `$rootScope`, is used

## Scope inheritance of functions

```
<div ng-controller="Parent">
  <div ng-controller="Child">
    <div ng-controller="ChildOfChild">
       <button ng-click="someParentFunctionInScope()">Do</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or, in code

```
.controller("ChildOfChild", function($scope){
   $scope.someParentFunctionInScope();
});
```

**Advantages:**

- Good for top-to-bottom data propagation

**Disadvantages:**

- Not-as-good for bottom-to-top, since it requires an object (as opposed to a primitive)
- Calling ancestor functions creates a tight coupling
- Does not work between siblings, unless a common ancestor, like `$rootScope`, is used

## Scope inheritance + `$watch`

Controllers only react to change in scope-exposed data and never call functions.

```
.controller("Parent", function($scope){
  $scope.VM = {a: "a", b: "b"};
  $scope.$watch("VM.a", function(newVal, oldVal){
    // react
  });
}
```

**Advantages:**

- Good for child scope not created by controllers, e.g. like within `ng-repeat`

**Disadvantages:**

- Doesn't work at all for one-time events
- Not very readable code

### Other notable mentions:

- Shared Service with specialized functionality
- More general Pub/Sub Service
- `$rootScope`

Comment: You may want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638563/angularjs-pubsub-vs-broadcast

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use functionality-specific shared services to communicate between controllers.

You can create a generic shared service to have a central point to subscribe to and broadcast events, but I find functionality-specific services to be easier to maintain over time, especially as the project and team grows.

Answer (score 6):

As [Samuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118703/samuel-neff) said, using a service to sharing data is a recommended method. The idea is that the state of the data are maintained consistently, regardless of any controller.
This two articles can give you an idea of "how to" and "why": [Sharing Data Between Controllers](https://thinkster.io/egghead/sharing-data-between-controllers/), [The state of angularjs controllers](http://jonathancreamer.com/the-state-of-angularjs-controllers/).

Answer (score 0):

-- There is another option to **inheritance** and share data between your controllers:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    var parent = function($scope){
        $scope.parent = {
             parentData: 'some data'
        }
    };

    // you could do some prototyping as well
//parent.prototype.parent2 = {
//    parentData: 'some more data'
//};

    var child = function($scope){
        parent.call(this, $scope);
        //$scope.parent2 = this.parent2; here is how you access that data.
    };
    child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
    child.prototype.constructor = child;


app.controller('parent', parent);

app.controller('myController', child);
```

This approach give you an advantage:

- Works with siblings scopes and DOM structure is not needed.

You could continue working with the objects creating custom properties, 'freezing' the data variables to persist the same data and ensure data is not modified, etc.

At the end, I prefer to use a service to share data between controllers and use the observer pattern or pub/sub with rootscope emit/on to acknowledge of actions within controllers.