# How to pass a result from modal of angular-ui-bootstrap to parent without closing?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

according to the https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal, I want to pass a result from modal to the parent without closing but in the example code, they only show a passing result to parent via closing

```
$uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
```

I want to pass a data to parent when the item is clicked but I do not know to do it. I really need help. Thanks.

Comment: you can use event, a shared service etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quite common problem about communicating between controllers since you don't want to close the model and wants to pass the data to a different controller.

The quickest path to your problem is using `$broadcast`. In the controller of your modal, write like this:

```
// Make sure to use $rootScope
$rootScope.$broadcast("modalDataEventFoo", {selectedItem: $scope.selected.item});
```

Now, in your parent controller:

```
$scope.$on("modalDataEventFoo", function(event, data) {
     console.log("got the data from modal", data.selectedItem);
});
```

Other references for communication between controllers:

1. [What's the correct way to communicate between controllers in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs)
2. https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers
3. http://www.angulartutorial.net/2014/03/communicate-with-controllers-in-angular.html
4. [Communication between controllers in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751889/communication-between-controllers-in-angular)

Comment: Note that the arguments passed to the listener function are: (event, data) and not just (data) as shown in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to **share the scope** between the parent controller and the modal controller declaring `scope` property in the options:

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size: size,
  scope: $scope,
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});
```

Check this plunker in which the modal contains an input element bound to the variable `$scope.shared.name`:
http://plnkr.co/edit/4xiEXATxAnvDKBSXxzQd