# $rootScope.$broadcast vs. $scope.$emit

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Now that the performance difference between `$broadcast` and `$emit` has been eliminated, is there any reason to prefer `$scope.$emit` to `$rootScope.$broadcast`?

They are different, yes.

`$emit` is restricted to the scope hierarchy (upwards) - this may be good, if it fits your design, but it seems to me a rather arbitrary restriction.

`$rootScope.$broadcast` works across all that *choose* to listen to the event, which is a more sensible restriction in my mind.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

To clarify in response to an answer, the direction of the dispatch is not the issue I'm after. `$scope.$emit` dispatches the event upwards, and `$scope.$broadcast` - downwards. But why not always use `$rootScope.$broadcast` to reach all the intended listeners?

Comment: http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/ has it all

Answer (score 1186, accepted):

**tl;dr** *(this tl;dr is from [@sp00m](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26752415/699294)'s answer below)*

> `$emit` dispatches an event upwards ... `$broadcast` dispatches an event downwards

**Detailed explanation**

`$rootScope.$emit` only lets other `$rootScope` listeners catch it. This is good when you don't want every `$scope` to get it. Mostly a high level communication. Think of it as adults talking to each other in a room so the kids can't hear them.

`$rootScope.$broadcast` is a method that lets pretty much everything hear it. This would be the equivalent of parents yelling that dinner is ready so everyone in the house hears it.

`$scope.$emit` is when you want that `$scope` and all its parents and `$rootScope` to hear the event. This is a child whining to their parents at home (but not at a grocery store where other kids can hear).

`$scope.$broadcast` is for the `$scope` itself and its children. This is a child whispering to its stuffed animals so their parents can't hear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The focus of my question was why to use scope hierarchy as a way to restrict the audience? The audience is already "restricted" in the sense that controllers choose what to listen to. I clarified in the question that I understand perfectly the distinction between `$emit` and `$broadcast`, but I don't understand the need for restriction based on scope hierarchy.

Comment: @NewDev The reason is because often you have repetition of scopes on the page. If you have two or more scopes representing different instances of data - e.g. a list of patient records on a page, each with its own scope - then it won't work to broadcast from the root an event that is intended for just one of those scopes. Avoiding `$rootScope` broadcasts where possible allows better reuse.

Comment: Nothing you've said is wrong, but a way to generalize it that $emit goes down the document to child scopes and $emit goes up the document to parent scopes. Both will trigger any listeners attached to the current scope.

Comment: One point is missed. $emit can be cancelled once executed, $broadcast however, cannot be cancelled.
Good examples BTW!

Comment: This answer may be outdated.  `broadcast` is not like "screaming parents".  Broadcast is the inverse of emit.  emit targets parents.  broadcast targets children. Which method is "louder" depends on how many parents vs children the broadcaster/emitter itself has.  See "Scope Events Propagation" at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Answer (score 106):

They are not doing the same job: `$emit` dispatches an event **upwards** through the scope hierarchy, while `$broadcast` dispatches an event **downwards** to all child scopes.

Comment: Yes, I noted that in the question (perhaps I could have made it clear about the direction of the dispatch). But I also noted that that is a rather arbitrary restriction. If I can reach my "listener", why can't I always do this downwards from `$rootScope`?

Comment: Because an $emit won't affect a scope's child or sibling scopes. These just map to javascript's event propagation types - capturing and bubbling. $broadcast is used for capturing and $emit is used for bubbling.  There's a now seemingly ancient quirksmode article that explains the difference pretty well: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 81):

I made the following graphic out of the following link: https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

[image: Scope, rootScope, emit, broadcast]

As you can see, `$rootScope.$broadcast` hits a lot more listeners than `$scope.$emit`.

Also, `$scope.$emit`'s bubbling effect can be cancelled, whereas `$rootScope.$broadcast` cannot.

Comment: I see a lot of arrows.

Comment: @MichalStefanow I'm a fan of visual answers :)

Comment: @mparnisari :.

$broadcast(name, args) - Broadcast an event down through the $scope of all children

.$emit(name, args) - Emit an event up the $scope hierarchy to all parents, including the $rootScope

Answer (score 22):

[image]

$scope.$emit:  This method dispatches the event in the upwards direction (from child to  parent)

[image]
$scope.$broadcast: Method dispatches the event in the downwards direction (from parent to child)  to all the child controllers.

[image]
$scope.$on: Method registers to listen to some event. All the controllers which are listening to that event get notification of the broadcast or emit based on 
the where those fit in the child-parent hierarchy.

The $emit event can be cancelled by any one of the $scope who is listening to the event.

The $on provides the "stopPropagation" method. By calling this method the event can be stopped from propagating further.

Plunker :https://embed.plnkr.co/0Pdrrtj3GEnMp2UpILp4/

In case of sibling scopes (the scopes which are not in the direct parent-child hierarchy) then $emit and $broadcast will not communicate to the sibling scopes.

[image]

For more details please refer to 
http://yogeshtutorials.blogspot.in/2015/12/event-based-communication-between-angularjs-controllers.html

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: The objective was to provide the working plunker, however, I have added the appropriate description here.

Answer (score 4):

@Eddie has given a perfect answer of the question asked.
But I would like to draw attention to using an more efficient approach of Pub/Sub.

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21639013/842386) answer suggests,

> The $broadcast/$on approach is not terribly efficient as it broadcasts to all the scopes(Either in one direction or both direction of Scope hierarchy). While the Pub/Sub approach is much more direct. Only subscribers get the events, so it isn't going to every scope in the system to make it work.

you can use [`angular-PubSub`](https://github.com/georapbox/angular-PubSub) angular module. once you add `PubSub` module to your app dependency, you can use `PubSub` service to subscribe and unsubscribe events/topics.

Easy to subscribe:

```
// Subscribe to event
var sub = PubSub.subscribe('event-name', function(topic, data){
    
});
```

Easy to publish

```
PubSub.publish('event-name', {
    prop1: value1,
    prop2: value2
});
```

To unsubscribe, use `PubSub.unsubscribe(sub);` OR `PubSub.unsubscribe('event-name');`.

**NOTE** Don't forget to unsubscribe to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

### Use RxJS in a Service

> What about in a situation where you have a Service that's holding state for example. How could I push changes to that Service, and other random components on the page be aware of such a change? Been struggling with tackling this problem lately

Build a service with [RxJS Extensions for Angular](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js).

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/rx/dist/rx.all.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/rx-angular/dist/rx.angular.js"></script>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['rx']);

app.factory("DataService", function(rx) {
  var subject = new rx.Subject(); 
  var data = "Initial";

  return {
      set: function set(d){
        data = d;
        subject.onNext(d);
      },
      get: function get() {
        return data;
      },
      subscribe: function (o) {
         return subject.subscribe(o);
      }
  };
});
```

Then simply subscribe to the changes.

```
app.controller('displayCtrl', function(DataService) {
  var $ctrl = this;

  $ctrl.data = DataService.get();
  var subscription = DataService.subscribe(function onNext(d) {
      $ctrl.data = d;
  });

  this.$onDestroy = function() {
      subscription.dispose();
  };
});
```

Clients can subscribe to changes with `DataService.subscribe` and producers can push changes with `DataService.set`.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/YVKGhCx0DrzyzckMDjtv?p=preview).