# which is best to use $rootScope.$emit or $$rootScope.$broadcast for angularjs loader indicator in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

$rootScope.$emit flows up to $rootScope and $rootScope.$broadcast flows down the scope to $rootScope and all $scope's in angularjs. I am still confused of what exactly to use for angularjs loader indicator .

Comment: can you explain a little better what the question is exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$rootScope.$emit` only lets other `$rootScope` listeners catch it. This is good when you don't want every $scope to get it.

`$rootScope.$broadcast` is a method that lets pretty much everything hear it.

This might help, You can refer to the original answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752030/rootscope-broadcast-vs-scope-emit)