# Which is more 'expensive'? $watch or $emit/$on in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Really, I have a dilemma - and I'm sure I'm not the only one. Sometimes I'm conflicted between using `$emit/$on` communication, and just `$watch` on a scope to fire events. I am sure the answer is something like "depends on how many listeners etc." - but was wondering if 1:1 there was a better practice?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of both are different. So the question title `Which is more 'expensive'? $watch or $emit/$on in AngularJS?` is not useful as if it is expensive or not.

You can see the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) in more details.

## watch:

> Registers a listener callback to be executed whenever the watchExpression changes.

## on:

> Listens on events of a given type.

---

So, the watch is used to consider if the variable or object is going to change? Then apply it.

And the on method is used to consider sharing event between each-other. So from parent you can broadcast the event and the child can emit the broadcasted event.

---

You may also be interested the followings:

[watch and apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/angularjs-using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply)

[working with on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on)

[broadcast vs emit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752030/rootscope-broadcast-vs-scope-emit)