# angular rootscope broadcast from a service

Tags: angularjs

I heard its a bad practice to use rootscope $on from a controller, because when a controller is destroyed, the event listener is not. If I use it from a service and inject it to the controller, like below, will it prevent memory leaks?

```
.service("hiEventService",function($rootScope) {
    this.broadcast = function() {$rootScope.$broadcast("hi")}
    this.listen = function(callback) {$rootScope.$on("hi",callback)}
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is going to 'prevent' memory leaks because it never gets destroyed through out the lifetime of the application because every even is getting registered on `$rootScope`.

Best practice would be to destroy the listener on scope destruction.

For example, if there is a controller that's listening to an event like so,

```
$scope.$on('anEvent', function(){});
```

there is no need to destroy the listener as the listeners will be automatically unregistered on scope destruction, automatically.

On the other hand if the event is registered on `$rootScope`,

```
var eventHandle = $rootScope.$on('anEvent', function(){});
```

the even can be (and should be) destroyed by executing the `eventHandle` (which is a function) on scope destroy:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
    eventHandle();
});
```

And also, try to avoid broadcasting events on `$rootScope`. Try using `$emit` and `$broadcast` on child scopes. More info: [$rootScope.$broadcast vs. $scope.$emit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752030/rootscope-broadcast-vs-scope-emit)

Comment: In that case, why do they say it is best practice to put the event dispatcher/listener in a service? @Chanthu

Comment: I guess one reason might be that the `api` would be a lot cleaner. The method that's getting invoked would have a meaningful name, no need to duplicate the event name. Other than that, not sure.