# Angular $on not working

Tags: angularjs, controller, parent-child

I have two controllers (Main controller and Child controller). I am trying to pass value from Main to Child controller.

Here are the controllers:

```
.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'CIFactory', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, CIFactory) {

    $scope.moveTool = function (buildServerTool) {  //Am calling this moveTool function from View
        $scope.tool = buildServerTool.toolname;
        $scope.$broadcast('update_parent_controller', $scope.tool);
    };
}])

.controller('childController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$q', '$timeout', '$log', 'CIFactory', function ($scope, $rootScope, $q, $timeout, $log, CIFactory) {

    $scope.$on('update_parent_controller', function (event, tools) {
        $scope.tools = tools;
    });
}])
```

When I debug, control is going in moveTool() function, but it is not going inside $on(i.e., value in tools is not assigned to `$scope.tools`. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

As Martijn said `$broadcast` moves down the `$scope` chain, so it may be best to use `$rootScope` if the child controller isnt directly inside the parent scope

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('update_parent_controller', $scope.tool);
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28156845/94278) for more information on emit vs broadcast and scopes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chris. I have also tried another method and it worked for me. Instead of using $broadcast and $on, I just used following line in child controller,

```
   $scope.tools = $scope.$parent.tool;
```

So, the above code took the $scope value from parent controller and assigned to new scope $scope.tools, which I have used in corresponding View.