# Trigger to click on an html element in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a directive. When I click on an element with the "click-to-edit" directive, a text field is displayed to edit the content.

[image]
[image]

I want when I click on the button, this behavior continues to occur.
I need that when the button is clicked, it is equivalent to click on the directive. How can I achieve this?

```
    <label>Sprint name:</label> <div click-to-edit type="inputText" ng-model="sprintName"></div>
    <br/>
    <input type='button' value='trigger Directive' ng-click='triggerDirective()'>
   </div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNQRLY

Comment: haven't looked too deeply through the code but one thing to consider is using an angular event that gets broadcast in `triggerDirective()` and listen for it in directive

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to angular, I have no idea how to do it. Can you help me please?

Comment: read some tutorials on using angular scope events

Comment: @charlietfl You can give me a link, example or something like that, I do not know how to search...

Comment: [all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you have to do, you can use [angular events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717493/usage-of-broadcast-emit-and-on-in-angularjs) or [you can share an object through isolate scope and add a function to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18487942/3354228).

Examples:

**1- With Angularjs Events:** ([PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/reCuu0k491iWHiuwum5A?p=preview))

*HTML:*

```
<div click-to-edit></div>
<button type="button" ng-click="item.toggle()">Toggle from Controller</button>
```

*Controller:*

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.toggle = function(){
        //Emit the event
        $scope.$broadcast('app.myEvent');
    };
});
```

*Directive:*

```
app.directive('clickToEdit', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: `
            <div ng-show="editState">
                <div>
                    <input type="text"/>
                    <button type="button" ng-click="item.toggle()">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        `,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.editState = false;

            scope.toggle = function () {
                scope.editState = !scope.editState;
            }

            //Listen and handler the event
            scope.$on('app.myEvent', function(event){
                scope.toggle();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

---

**2- Share object through isolate scope:** ([PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/JBv2ujUrWDDAxOWWhcRO?p=preview))

*HTML:*

```
<div click-to-edit item="item"></div>
<button type="button" ng-click="item.toggle()">Toggle from Controller</button>
```

*Controller:*

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.item = {};
});
```

*Directive:*

```
app.directive('clickToEdit', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            item: '='
        }
        template: `
            <div ng-show="editState">
                <div>
                    <input type="text"/>
                    <button type="button" ng-click="item.toggle()">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        `,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.editState = false;

            //Here you add the function to the isolate scope 'item' variable
            scope.item.toggle = function () {
                scope.editState = !scope.editState;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your time, but this is complex, my idea is to include each button in a ng-repeat and when I click the button, I want the corresponding text field to appear.

Comment: So, you can take advantage of second approach. Isn't too complex do it inside of `ng-repeat`, I will update my answer. But where do you place the toggleDirective button if you have an ng-repeat? What should do that button? Toggle all records?

Comment: look this picture. you are very friendly http://i.imgur.com/TGbjjTl.jpg

Comment: On each button I click, and then I can edit the field.

Comment: So, you have a toggle button for each item of ng-repeat.. something like this [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/s5ay16Cs4ByBuPlUb0Km?p=preview) (obliviously is not an accordion, is just a table, but is the same approach)

Comment: great! hablas español? do you speak spanish?

Comment: Yes, I'm from Argentina. If you want I can update my answer.

Comment: yo soy de colombia, te puedo hablar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145400/discussion-between-yavg-and-the-bear).

Answer (score 0):

Modify the directive, inside which add click bind event for the button control. So when the directive is called , it binds the click event on your button. 
Hope this helps !

Comment: Can you please give me an example? My idea is to have this in a ng-repeat. And each button should do what I want, according to the button clicked...