# angularJS validate input field with the help of $emit and $on

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, broadcast, angularjs-controller, emit

I am creating a web app in which I want to validate some of my input fields

so I am using `$emit` and `$on` to keep it short

I created a directive which looks like this

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('validateFields', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$on('validateInputFields', function (param) {
            if (param == undefined || param == null || param == '') {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I want to execute this directive and return true or false as per result(I know this is incorrect but I am very new in directives and $emit $on)

and I am calling this in my controller

```
$scope.$emit('validateInputFields', $scope.mddoh);
```

but this is printing an object

```
{name: "validateInputFields", targetScope: b, stopPropagation: ƒ, preventDefault: ƒ, defaultPrevented: false, …}
```

what is the best way to use $emit and $on in my scenerio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$scope.$emit`  in your Controller to

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('validateInputFields', $scope.mddoh);
```

and in your Directive, change `scope.$on` to

```
$rootScope.$on
```

and don't forget to inject `$rootScope`.

Comment: can you please tell me the difference between broadcast and emit

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752030/rootscope-broadcast-vs-scope-emit and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717493/usage-of-broadcast-emit-and-on-in-angularjs