# Scope variable not updating when select changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `select` dropdown I'm setting up with an `ng-options`. It's showing up fine in the HTML page, but when I select an option, the variable defined by `ng-model` is not being updated in `$scope`.

HTML:

```html
<select ng-model="selected_ingredient"
        ng-options="item as item.ingredient for item in available_ingredients"
        ng-change="selectIngredient()">
    <option value="">Add an ingredient...</option>
</select>
```

AngularJS:

```js
$scope.selectIngredient = function() {
    if ( $scope.debug > 0 ) {
        console.log( "Selected ingredient:" );
        console.log( $scope.selected_ingredient );
    }
};
```

Console output (after dropdown item selected, `$scope.debug` is 1):

```
Selected ingredient:
undefined
```

I would like `$scope.selected_ingredient` to be the object `item` that is displayed by the dropdown element I select. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should look into using $emit and $broadcast for angular js (old school angular) versions when dealing with updating. I also wouldn't bind directly to a $scope variable but a local and then set scope from within $emit or $broadcast. Here's a decent SO on it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717493/usage-of-broadcast-emit-and-on-in-angularjs

Comment: @billy_comic thanks for the reply. I gave this a try but had a similar failure, documented in my edited post above. Let me know if I've missed something.

Comment: @billy_comic scratch that - it worked when I took braces around my call to the scope variable I'm sending via `$emit` as detailed in my edited edit. Since the actual call is in the HTML, I thought it would need to be wrapped, but it should not; I couldn't find a reason why in the SO you sent and its references, so if you have the time to explain why that would be really helpful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a workaround from @billy_comic in the comments

```html
<select ng-model="$parent.selected_ingredient"
        ng-options="item as item.name for item in available_ingredients"
        ng-change="$emit( 'SelectedIngredient', $parent.selected_ingredient )">
    <option value="">Add an ingredient...</option>
</select>
```

in my HTML as well as the following JS function

```js
$scope.$on( "SelectedIngredient" , function( evt, data ) {
    if ( $scope.debug > 0 ) {
        console.log( "Selected ingredient:" );
        console.log( data );
    }
});
```

that produces the expected values. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work for me. Maybe you've made a mistake in the initialization or in some part of the code you haven't shown.

```js
angular.module("exampleApp", [])
  .controller("selectIngredientCtrl", function ($log, $scope) {
    $scope.availableIngredients = [
      {ingredient: "foo"},
      {ingredient: "bar"},
      {ingredient: "baz"},
    ];
    $scope.selectedIngredient = null;
    $scope.selectIngredient = () => {
      $log.log($scope.selectedIngredient?.ingredient);
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="exampleApp" ng-controller="selectIngredientCtrl">
  <select
    ng-model="selectedIngredient"
    ng-options="item as item.ingredient for item in availableIngredients"
    ng-change="selectIngredient()"
  >
    <option value="">
      Add an ingredient...
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```