# How do I put a variable in $scope in ALL my controllers

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have a variable flag called is_logged_in, I want it to be in scope in all my controllers. So that if I have {{is_logged_in}} on every page in my app, it will print it out.

How do I achieve this **without writing duplicate code like this**, in all my controllers:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, IsLoggedInService) {
$scope.is_logged_in = IsLoggedInService.IsLoggedIn();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the `$rootScope`. This, as the name implies, correspond to the root scope of your application and is therefore potentially available (via DI) in any of your controllers.  All you need to do is add `$rootScope` as a DI dependency in each of your controllers that requires it:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $rootScope {
  $rootScope...
}
```

In your templates, the `$rootScope` always available by referencing `$root` in an angular expression.

You would do something like this:

```
<p>{{$root.is_logged_in}}</p>
```

Comment: This worked thanks! Though I am going to incorporate some of mavim's answer for logged in only pages

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
$rootScope.is_logged_in = IsLoggedInService.IsLoggedIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check whether the user is logged in or not
i think the right approach to your problem is to use resolve property in the route, so the user can't navigate to certain pages if he isn't logged in and once he logged in you can inject the user object to the controller

for example to navigate to home page you must be logged in

```
.when("/home", {
templateUrl: "homeView.html",
controller: "homeController",
resolve: {
    user: function(AuthenticationService){
        return AuthenticationService.getUser();
    }
  }
})

app.controller("homeController", function ($scope, user) {
  $scope.user = user;
});
```

https://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-authentication-angular-applications/

and if you just want a global variable you can use $rootScope

Answer (score -1):

Another approach, yet using the $rootScope, is to use **$broadcast** to create an observer for that variable.

In order to do this, you should broadcast an event when this variable is changed, like this:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('user_logged_in');
```

And then, watch it using the $on method. Here:

```
$scope.$on('user_logged_in', function(event, args) {
    // here you do what you want, like:
    $scope.logged_in = true;
});
```

If you want to know more about it, angular also provides the $emmit method, that is used when you want that scopes above yours listen to that event. ( you can find more here : [$rootScope.$broadcast vs. $scope.$emit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752030/rootscope-broadcast-vs-scope-emit)

Yet, you should read more about in the **docs**, [What are scopes?](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) and here: [$rootScope.Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: For this to work correctly both the controllers from where broadcast is done to where it is received should be active at the same time as it is nothing but an event listener