# Why is rootscope.on not triggered?

Tags: angularjs, broadcast, emit

I am using $scope.$emit in my ListController to trigger a $rootScope.$on event in the MainController(angular 1.3):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('mymodule.faultlist')
        .controller('MainController', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
            $rootScope.$on('newViewLoaded', function (event, metadata) {
                $rootScope.metadata = metadata;
                console.log('hello metacontroller metadata', metadata);
            });

        }])
        .controller('ListController', ['faultlistservice', 'faultListConstants', '$scope', '$timeout', '$rootScope',
            function (faultlistservice, faultListConstants, $scope, $timeout, $rootScope) {

                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.$emit('newViewLoaded', {
                        'title': faultListConstants.meta.title,
                        'description': faultListConstants.meta.description
                    });
                }, 100);

            }]);
})();
```

This is what the index.html roughly looks like:

```
.
.
<head ng-controller="MainController">
<div class="container main-content" ui-view >
</div>
..
```

This does not get triggered. I tried moving the $rootScope.$on block to the ListController and then the $rootScope.$on gets triggered. Why is this not working for the MainController or is there a better way of implementing this?

Comment: @TheHeadRush Seems it is the same question!!!

Comment: Is MainController parent if ListController? Can you share the HTML?

Comment: yes MainController is defined at top ie defined in head tag. The ListController sits within the ui-view (ui-router). The MainController is not defined in a stateprovider.

Comment: Doh! i posted the wrong link. Thanks for pointing that out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752030/rootscope-broadcast-vs-scope-emit

Comment: @The Head Rush if $scope.emit goes up then I assume that the $rootScope.$on would fire according to the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code works http://plnkr.co/edit/hsl3l6rTJd1SUDgaijCy?p=preview

I think your problem might be in that you have ng-app not on html tag, so `<head ng-controller="MainController">` this line is outside ngApp.

Answer (score 0):

your code works properly http://plnkr.co/edit/nX9KVqY0SZ46Yvf92VAk?p=preview

The plunkr shows how you can you use this example to work with your original code. The title and description over here are arguments to be passed inside the emit function and cannot be string literals

```
 $scope.$emit('newViewLoaded', {
                        'title': faultListConstants.meta.title,
                        'description': faultListConstants.meta.description
                    })
```