# How to set same broadcast in two places

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-broadcast

I have a piece of code that needs to be invoked after execution of some other code. i'm using `broadcast` for this. I need to invoke the same code from 2 different places. Now that is not working for me.
My code is

Broadcast 1

```
scope.$broadcast('selOrdLine', ordline);
```

On

```
scope.$on('selOrdLine', function (event, args) {
 // some code here
})
```

I need to invoke this code from some other place also

so I put `scope.$broadcast('selOrdLine', ordline);` there also. But it is returning error.

**Edit**

The second time when I use `broadcast` I'm making the `ordline` data using the `angular.forEach` loop. so I'm using `$q` for running the broadcast only after the data is ready like this

```
$q.all(orderline).then(function () {
    $scope.$broadcast('selOrdLine', orderline);
});
```

The error is, the `broadcast` is invoked multiple times. But as I use `$q` it should run only after the orderline data is set, right ?

Comment: There is no such restriction from angular than you can't fire same event from two places. I think the error is for something else. Can you put the error message here?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You probably want $rootScope.$broadcast instead of scope.$broadcast

Comment: It might be some orther error. broadcast works multiple time in multiple places

Comment: You may want to read this fine [answer about event firing and handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752030/rootscope-broadcast-vs-scope-emit). It may help you to figure it out by yourself.