# Drag and drop Angular 1.x directive/component and parent scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-components

Let's say my grandparent component/directive's scope variable is declared like this: `$scope.g = { // methods here };`

In each of my nested component's/directive's controllers, I'm referring to that variable like `$scope.$parent.$parent.g` and then calling some function off of `g` such as `$scope.fromNgClick = function() { $scope.$parent.$parent.g.run(); };`. That works great (though I would like a better way of referring to ancestors such as an alias name? instead of a $parent chain).

When I natively drag a component from it's grandparent component into another grandparent sibling component (got that?), the same `$scope.fromNgClick = function() { $scope.$parent.$parent.g.run(); };` still points to the original scope, not the new one like I need it to.  So clicking the same ng-clickable element still triggers the `run()` method on the previous grandparent's scope.

That all makes sense; but, is there a way to get the scope to point to the new dropped locations grandparent scope instead?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
The markup would be something like the following where `<g-directive>` is treated as a grandparent because it uses `transclude` on its template, ultimately wrapping the child directives:

```
<g-directive>
    <child-directive></child-directive>
    <another-child-directive></another-child-directive>
    <yet-another-child-directive></yet-another-child-directive>
</g-directive>
<g-directive>
    <c-child-directive></c-child-directive>
    <c-another-child-directive></c-another-child-directive>
    <c-yet-another-child-directive></c-yet-another-child-directive>
</g-directive>
```

That's the reason for the `$scope.$parent.$parent.g` on the child directives/components.

A child component can be dragged and then dropped into another `<g-directive>` but it's controller still points to its original grandparent (original `<g-directive>`'s controller scope variable). I want it to point to the new grandparent is was dropped into, essentially resetting it's scope to the newly placed scope.

Comment: if you want to have a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs
Not sure why you need to call so many parents from your current scope.

Comment: @maddog I think that is helpful for some other situations, but I don't know how that would resolve the child's scope reference to a new grandparent.

Comment: you can `emit` and `broadcast` to call other controllers. and use sharing service or a `$rootScope` variable to share data.

Comment: @maddog In this case though, even with emiting pseudo events to call methods, how do I differentiate between which <g-directive> needs to be called if all <g-directive> instances are watching for the same event?  These are all dynamic. I could have any number of <g-directive>'s with any number of nested directives/components and those nested components need to only ever trigger their *current* <g-directive>'s method for whichever one they've been moved/dropped into at that moment. Even passing in data wouldn't let me know which parent is the current one as they can start anywhere. :/

Comment: i think this might solve your problem (scope.emit): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752030/rootscope-broadcast-vs-scope-emit

Comment: also you can assign numbers from your code to specific parents/child

Comment: @maddog That was a really good article and works really well generally, but even when using that method, the pointers are still on the original scope the child component was within.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116736/discussion-between-atomtech-and-maddog).

Answer (score 0):

```
<g-directive some-attr=1>
 <child-directive></child-directive some-attr=1>
 <another-child-directive></another-child-directive some-attr=1>
 <yet-another-child-directive></yet-another-child-directive some-attr=1>
</g-directive>

<g-directive some-attr=2>
 <child-directive></child-directive some-attr=2>
 <another-child-directive></another-child-directive some-attr=2>
 <yet-another-child-directive></yet-another-child-directive some-attr=2>
</g-directive>
```

Each can have different listener for `broadcast` and `emit`.

if the directives are repeated through `ng-repeat` then the `$index` can be that attribute. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the details yesterday.  Instead of doing that work around, I managed to change the wrapping component's structure to address the some of the functionality I originally had assigned to the nested components, and that has been working okay for my use-case.