# Angular rootscope.brodcast is not firing event

Tags: angularjs

This is  my  controller which is broadcasting the request on every button click ! but it is not firing any event !

```
app.controller("education-blog", function ($scope, $http, $state, $ionicPopup, blogfav,URL, educationB, $cordovaSocialSharing, $localStorage, $rootScope) {
    $scope.edu = educationB.getEdu($state.params.id);


    $scope.class = $scope.edu.is_favorite;
    $localStorage.blogscount = 0;

    $scope.favbutton = function (id) {
        if ($scope.class === true) {
            $scope.class = false;
        }
        else {
            $scope.class = true;
        }
        var data = {
            id: id,
            type: 'blogs'
        };
        $http.post(URL.url+'/favorites', data).success(function (response) {
            console.log(response.is_favorite);
            if (response.is_favorite == true) {
                $localStorage.blogscount++;
            }
            if (response.is_favorite == false) {
                $localStorage.blogscount--;
            }
        }).error(function () {
            $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Something went wrong !',
                template: ' Sorry for the Inconvenience !'
            });
        });
        $rootScope.$broadcast('update', 9);
    }
});
```

this is my second controller which contain $scope.on()//

```
    app.controller('blogfav', function (blogfav, $scope) {

        $scope.blogfavourites = blogfav;

        $scope.$on('update', function (event, arg) {
            $scope.receiver = 'got your ' + arg;
            console.log($scope.receiver);
        });
```

**what I want is when i click on my favbutton it must fire the event which must be catch by my second controller**

**These two are separate controllers**

Comment: did you tried with an $emit ?

Comment: ok and what if you put the $rootScope.$broadcast('update', 9); in the $http success ?

Comment: nothing happens sir :(

Comment: just FYI `$http.success/.error` are deprecated. `.then/.catch` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

I can only imagine  that the two controllers do not share a `$rootScope`.

Perhaps they belong to different modules/apps, and are not 'visible' to each other.

[$rootScope.$broadcast vs. $scope.$emit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752030/rootscope-broadcast-vs-scope-emit) is a good explanation of how broadcast and emit work in angularjs.

Comment: Actually, I am having a problem that when my controller which needs to catch is not open once (means it is not registered at least once!) it is not catching up the event else it is catching the events ! 

what should I do ? if my controller is not registered ? and i can still make it catch the request ?

Comment: This answer is good, I just want to add that the 2 controllers might be defined in the same module, but the first one broadcasts on $rootScope and the second one listens on its personal $scope. It seems very unlikely that these 2 are the same.

Comment: @deepdownunder2222 my understanding was that `$rootScope.broadcast` would go down to *all* scopes, which is picked up by the `on` or each scope.

Comment: @KartikKhandelwal I'm struggling to understand what you've said. Are you saying that you have two modules? Can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38996710/edit) your post to show us where you define your module (`app = angular.module` or similar) and where the two controllers are 'used' (either `<div ng-controller ="....">` or in say your `routeProvider`)?

Comment: @Pureferret, you are absolutely right. I made a short refresh and $rootScope.$broadcast indeed sends the message to both the listeners registering $rootScope.$on and the ones that have a child scope and register $scope.$on, since $broadcast's way of working is downstream (all children scopes are elligible to be notified), as opposed to $emit.

Comment: @pureferret , actually my code is not working bcoz my second controller is not registered to handle the request ?  what I found is that ! when I open the page of the second controller and then open the page of the first controller than when I do some operations then it works correctly ..but when I refresh my application and  open my first page before opening the second page  it won't work !
(my both controller are completely distinct) and on the different page !

Comment: (i need to ask one thing is -- do controller register themselves when we open the page ? )
or they register themselves in config file when app starts automatically

Comment: @KartikKhandelwal page loads, `<script>` tags are read, when they hit your code it's 'loaded'. Angular works out dependencies, and runs the right things when it's ready. One of those will be the controllers attached to the html on the page.