# $emit not working in controllers in different html pages

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 controllers and one service.From one controller calling service and result $emit to another controller in another page .but its not working.Please help.Thanks in advance.

### In first controller

```
routerApp.controller('DetailCtrl',['$scope''ChefService','$rootScope',function($scope,ChefService,$rootScope){
   $scope.Fn_ClickChefProfile = function(chefid){
    ChefService.GetChefProfile(chefid).then(function(d){
    $rootScope.$emit("CallToChef",d);
     });};]});
```

### In second controller

```
routerApp.controller('ChefCtrl',['$scope','$rootScope','ChefService',function($scope,$rootScope,ChefService){

$rootScope.$on("CallToChef",function(event,data){
  $scope.Fn_GetChefProfile(data);
 });
 $scope.Fn_GetChefProfile = function(data){
console.log(data);
 };}]);
```

Comment: sorry, another controller **in another page**?  Like you have two copies of the app running in different browser windows?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752030/rootscope-broadcast-vs-scope-emit)

$emit dispatches an event upwards (to parent controller) ... $broadcast dispatches an event downwards (to child controller)