# ngDialog opening multiple times

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

First time when I click on the link to open the dialog, it is opening only one time. But from the second time, it is opening two times, four times , eight times on second, third, fourth click respectively. Why is it opening multiple times?

Html code: header.html

```
<li><a href data-ng-click="chatBotFunction()" chat-bot>Chat</a></li>
```

JS code: headerCtrl.js

```
$scope.chatBotFunction = function() {
    $rootScope.$emit("CallChatMethod",{});
}
```

chatCtrl.js

```
$rootScope.$on("CallChatMethod", function(){
    $scope.openChatBox();
});

$scope.openChatBox = function() {
    ngDialog.openConfirm({
        template: 'modules/main/views/chatBot.html',
        controller: 'chatCtrl',
        closeByDocument: false,
        closeByEscape: false,
        showClose: false,
        scope: $scope 
    }).then(

    );  
};
```

Someone please help me solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, if you use `$rootScope.$on` the respective controller will not destroy even when you navigate to other pages. So try with `$scope.$on`

```
$scope.$on("CallChatMethod", function(){
    $scope.openChatBox();
});
```

> $scope.$broadcast is for when publishing from parent to child
>   $scope.$emit is for when publishing from child to parent

Let me knw if you still face problem.

Comment: I fear it may not work. I believe $rootScope.$emit only lets other $rootScope listeners catch it as mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752030/rootscope-broadcast-vs-scope-emit

Comment: Try it.. surely it will work. All are works under prototype concept only

Comment: Can u check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/31464/ . Not working when used with $scope.$emit

Comment: Use $scope.$broadcast, because u publishing from parent to child. U have to use emit only when u publish child to parent. check this link jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/31467/

Comment: It works when i use `$scope.$broadcast`. Thanks. And please include that in the answer , it will be useful for others :)

Comment: Sure ill add. If it is works kindly accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the listener on scope destroy event

```
var callChatListener = $rootScope.$on("CallChatMethod", function(){
   $scope.openChatBox();
});
```

Below code will remove listener from $rootscope

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function(){
   callChatListener(); 
});
```

Comment: I am getting an error, `TypeError: callChatListener is not a function`

Comment: Edited the answer. Check now

Comment: same error. `TypeError: this.callChatListener is not a function`