# getData function is not fired after broadcast in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
  $scope.gridconfig.getData = function (e) {
            ajaxCall.get('something?Id=' + $scope.clientModel.Id).then(function (data) {
                if (!data.IsError) {
                    $scope.result = data.Result;
                    $scope.gridconfig.ds = data.Result;
                    $scope.gridconfig.dataCount = data.Result.length;

                    e.success({ data: data.Result, total: $scope.gridconfig.dataCount });
                } else {

                    alertify.error(data.Message);
                }
            });
        }

        function loadGrid() {
            $timeout(function() {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('Grid');
            },1000);
        }
```

In js file after broadcast, getData is not fired. I have to call getData function whenever broadcast is called.
Please help me

Comment: where is `$scope.$on('Grid')`???

Comment: Show your full code

Comment: $scope.$on('Gird', function (e) {
                loadGrid();
                resizeGrid();
            });     This is present in my code

Comment: Don't know about your controllers relation.

Comment: https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$on('Gird', function (event, data) {
 loadGrid(); resizeGrid();
  });
```

> $emit dispatches an event upwards ... $broadcast dispatches an event
>   downwards

[$rootScope.$broadcast vs. $scope.$emit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752030/rootscope-broadcast-vs-scope-emit)

Comment: Can i see your full code..$broadcast : parent ctrl -> child ctrl, $emit: child ctrl -> parent ctrl