# best practices to notify change from service to controller in angular js

Tags: angularjs, notifications, angularjs-service

I have a common angular service and multiple controllers. My service is notified of a change which happens in server end. 
Now i want service to notify the controller of this change so that i can update some controller properties.

I have used `$rootscope.$broadcast` in service and `$scope.$on` in controller for achieving this. Is this a good practice to achieve it in this way.

Comment: there is no problem in using this method. check this you may get a better clarification http://stackoverflow.com/a/28156845/7333443

Comment: Thanks you! Is there any possibility of memory leaks in this method? I am going to use this in multiple controllers in my application. Please suggest.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing if you could tell me - i sit possible to reload a module's directive without actually reloading the page. Scenario is : i am using 'ui.bootstrap.datepicker' this angular js module for my application. My application is multilingual. If at backend language changes from LTR(english) to RTL (arabic) i need to update my UI without refreshing the page

Comment: It won't have memory leaks, but make sure that use that only when necessary and avoid unnecessary use of $watch in your system. I am posting an answer regarding do's and don't's

Comment: as @Rohit Jindal mentioned. you can use isolated scopes

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angularjs/1921/profiling-and-performance#t=201705220936409514068 for performance related stuffs

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand where we have to use [$rootscope.broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

Instead of using `$rootscope.$broadcast` you can directly `inject` the service into the controller and when ever controller is initialized changes into the service will reflect into the controller.

Comment: that's correct. But question here is : I want to notify my controller of an event happened in my service. This is after the initial load has happened.

Comment: If there is any event then you can use `$scope.$watch`.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing if you could tell me - i sit possible to reload a module's directive without actually reloading the page.
Scenario is : i am using 'ui.bootstrap.datepicker'  this angular js module for my application. My application is multilingual. If at backend language changes from LTR(english) to RTL (arabic) i need to update my UI without refreshing the page.

Comment: Yes you can do by using isolated scope in the directive..you can pass the language as a two way data binding symbol into the scope property of a directive.

Comment: thanks for the help

Comment: You can mark this answer as correct if it was useful for you so that it will help others as well.